# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: identification-request, symbols, swastika

[image]

The above images shows Swatika in the centre with different astras and a deity around it. What does it signify? Please provide the scriptural reference.

Comment: Are you sure that this is something Hindu?

Comment: @Rickross i do not know.But seems hindu from the shapes of the weapons and the deity

Comment: Which temple did you find this in? Depending on that there could be some relevance.

Comment: I highly doubt that this was something hindu.

Comment: To be honest I have seen this before but it wasn't in a hindu setting but I can't recall precisely so I may be wrong.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer @Pratimputra?

Comment: Have you tried showing this to a pandit?

Comment: Does not matter if they are aged or not the jiva atma lives on forever. Just kidding. Try several pandits maybe you will be suprised. Can't hurt asking for help.